# Azure Storage Table - Delete Item Error

Tags: azure-table-storage

I've been working on this issue for a while now and just can't get around it. Any help would be much appreciated...

Using Azure Table Storage (not development storage) I'm simply trying to delete a row from a table:

```
Public Sub DeleteByItemId(pairItemId As String)
    Dim item = (From c In _ServiceContext.UserTable Where c.Id = pairItemId Select c).Single()
    _ServiceContext.DeleteObject(item)
    _ServiceContext.SaveChanges()
End Sub
```

This causes an error: "The context is not currently tracking the entity."

And this approach:

```
Public Sub DeleteByItemId(itemId As String)
    Dim item = New <object type>
    item.PartitionKey = "sandbox"
    item.RowKey = itemId
    _ServiceContext.AttachTo(<table name>, item, "*")
    _ServiceContext.DeleteObject(item)
    _ServiceContext.SaveChanges()
End Sub
```

Errors with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code>InvalidInput</code>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">One of the request inputs is not valid.
RequestId:e37b0824-3336-4089-b6ac-2824438618f6
Time:2012-08-07T01:37:28.2741813Z</message>
</error>
```

How the service context gets created:

```
Public Sub New()
     Dim storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("DataConnectionString")
    _ServiceContext = New OroosoUserPairedAccountDataServiceContext(storageAccount.TableEndpoint.ToString(), storageAccount.Credentials)
    _ServiceContext.IgnoreResourceNotFoundException = True
    _ServiceContext.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking

    ' Create the tables
    ' In this case, just a single table.  
    storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient().CreateTableIfNotExist(<table name>)
End Sub
```

Fiddler hasn't revealed anything interesting.

I'm out of ideas...

Again, any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Someone edited my question to turn it into an answer, which served as a good reminder that it *was* actually a question. I'll move it here as a comment instead: Have you tried removing `_ServiceContext.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking`?

Comment: This worked. Not sure where that line came from originally. Why don't you put this in an answer so I can mark it as such...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `_ServiceContext.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking`. This is keeping the `DataServiceContext` from tracking the entity.